# Is there a way to recover a commit that was accidentally skipped during a rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

When it happens that a useful commit is accidentally skipped during a rebase operation, is there any hope that Git keeps a reference of it that could be reapplied?

It was a non-interactive rebase with lots of binary files where I went too long into a happy-trigger mood using `git rebase --skip`, so there were no error messages at all, just a lousy attitude.

This seems a hard-disk crashing recovery scenario, but instead of chasing phantom inodes, there should be a way to filter lost tree objects inside `.git/objects` and getting them back alive.

Comment: What do you mean by a commit that was accidentally "skipped" during a rebase? Are you saying that you left the commit out of the editor list during an interactive rebase, or that the rebase just didn't apply the commit like it was supposed to? What was the command that you used? What were the error messages?

Comment: @Cupcake, it was a non-interactive rebase with lots of binary files where I went too long a happy-trigger mood using `git rebase --skip`, so there was no error messages at all, just a lousy attitude.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you run `git rebase` (interactive or not), git basically does a series of `cherry-pick` operations to copy your original commit-chain to a new chain.  Let's use `o` for the original commits, and draw the commit-graph fragment for branch `branch` coming off branch `main`:

```
        o1 - o2 - o3 - o4   <-- branch
      /
..- * - x                   <-- main
```

Now you might run `git rebase` to copy all the old `o` commits to new `n` commits, but based off `x`, the tip of `main`, rather than based off `*`, the old merge-base point.  To make it even more like what happened, let's "accidentally" leave one out:

```
        o1 - o2 - o3 - o4   <-- ???
      /
..- * - x                   <-- main
          \
            n1 - n3 - n4    <-- branch
```

The `???` label above represents the git reference (branch-name, tag-name, or any other suitable label) that points or pointed to commit `o4`.  *All your old commits are still in there* as long as there's a name pointing to them.  If there's *no* name, they still stick around until `git gc` cleans them out (but you don't want that to happen so don't run `git gc` :-) ).

The important question, then, is: "what name or names can we (and git) use to find `o4`?"  It turns out there are at least two:

- one or more in a "reflog", and
- one spelled `ORIG_HEAD`.

The `ORIG_HEAD` one is the easiest to use, but that name is also used by other commands (`git merge`, for instance) so you have to see if it's still correct:

```
$ git log ORIG_HEAD
```

If that gives you the right chain, give yourself a more permanent name pointing to commit `o4`.  This can be a branch name (you thus "resurrect" the old branch under a new name), or a tag name, or indeed any other name but branch and tag are the easy ones:

```
$ git branch zombie ORIG_HEAD
```

(You don't *have* to do this, and as you get more comfortable with git you can skip this step, but it's probably good to do until then.)

---

What if `ORIG_HEAD` has been whacked (e.g., by another rebase, or merge, or whatever)?  Well, then there are reflogs.

There's one reflog for `HEAD`, and by default, another reflog for each branch-name.  In this case the one to use would be the reflog for `branch`:

```
$ git reflog branch
$ git log -g branch
```

but you can just use `git reflog` to show the one for `HEAD` (this one is noisier, which is why looking at the one just for `branch` might be better):

```
$ git reflog
$ git log -g
```

Somewhere in all that output, you should be able to find commit `o4`.  You might find lots of other commits that resemble `o4`, which is why `git log -g` can be helpful as it will let you find the real (or correct) `o4`.

In any case, assuming you eventually come up with a reflog style "relative name" (like `branch@{1}` or `branch@{yesterday}`), you can find the raw SHA-1, or use that relative name, to once again resurrect the zombie version of `branch`:

```
$ git branch zombie branch@{yesterday}
```

or:

```
$ git branch zombie feedd0gf00d
```

or whatever.

---

All this does is give you a name, `zombie`, where there were three question-marks in the drawing of the graph.  You still have to use that to find the dropped commit, in this case commit `o2`.  You can find it by raw SHA-1 (by reading through `git log`) and re-rebase and pull that one in, or cherry-pick it to append a copy to `n4`, or whatever.

If all you want to do is set `branch` back to commit `o4`, you can even dispense with the zombie branch entirely, and just do a `git reset --hard` while on branch `branch`:

```
$ git checkout branch           # if needed
$ git reset --hard feedd0gf00d
```

or:

```
$ git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

Note that the thing after `reset --hard` is just *any* commit-ID.  The `--hard` makes `reset` wipe out your work-tree and replace it with the target commit, while the `reset` action itself tells git: "make the current branch point to the commit-ID I'm about to give you, regardless of whatever branch-tip-commit it names right now."

In other words, after your `git rebase` finishes and you discover you left out `o2` when making the `n1 - n3 - n4` chain, if you immediately `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`, git changes this:<sup>1</sup>

```
        o1 - o2 - o3 - o4   <-- ORIG_HEAD
      /
..- * - x                   <-- main
          \
            n1 - n3 - n4    <-- HEAD=branch
```

to this:

```
        o1 - o2 - o3 - o4   <-- ORIG_HEAD, HEAD=branch
      /
..- * - x                   <-- main
          \
            n1 - n3 - n4    [abandoned]
```

The `[abandoned]` chain of `n` commits is actually still in the repo, of course: there's a name pointing to `n4` in the reflogs!

(The reflog entries eventually expire—by default, after 30 to 90 days, depending on details not yet interesting—and once they expire and there is no *name* by which to find `n4` or `o4` or whatever, *then* `git gc` will clean up and remove them.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that I've added the `HEAD=` notation to this graph, to indicate which branch you're on.  This `HEAD=` stuff is actually a pretty good approximation to how git keeps track of which branch you're on.  In the `.git` directory, there's a file named `HEAD`, and that file simply contains the name of the current branch!<sup>2</sup>  If you write a new name in the file, git changes its idea of which branch you're on (without changing anything else).  That's exactly what `git reset --soft` does: write a new name into `HEAD`.  (Using `--mixed` adds a little more action: `git reset` then updates the index/staging-area; and using `--hard` adds even more: `git reset` then wipes out work-directory contents, replacing them with whatever you've had it put into the `HEAD` file.)

<sup>2</sup>In "detached HEAD" mode, the file contains the raw SHA-1 of the current *commit*, instead of the name of the current *branch*.  That, in fact, is the real difference between being "on a branch" and being in "detached HEAD" mode.  When git wants to know what the current commit *is*, it looks at the file `HEAD`.  If it has a raw SHA-1, that's the answer.  If it has a branch name, git reads the branch-name to get the raw SHA-1.  Those are the only two allowed setups—nothing else should be in the `HEAD` file.

Answer (score 1):

does  `git reflog`  work for you? I think it should still be in the garbage collector unless you ran `git gc`

Comment: There is no "garbage collector" where dangling commits are stored until they're garbage collected.

Comment: @perlsufi, maybe a short receipt on how to use this command to track and revive the skipped commit. I don't have many clues on how it could be useful on that procedure and those `purge` words at the manpage are creeping  me out.

Comment: After reflog, get the SHA1 you want, then git merge that commit