# Why is a skipped commit not in the reflog after rebasing?

Tags: git

I rebased `branch-b` onto `branch-a` (non-interactive, but there were conflicts) and decided to `git rebase --skip` a particular commit that had too many conflicts. I can view the contents of this commit with `git show <SHA>` but the SHA does *not* show when I `git reflog`.

**Why is this?**

Refs:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recovering-lost-commits-in-git/

Comment: The reflog records which commits `HEAD` has pointed at. The skipped commit does not get checked out, and it is not applied either.

Comment: The reflog for each *branch*, however, contains the commits that that particular *branch name* pointed-to, so you can use the reflog for `branch-b` to find where it pointed previously, and then `git log branch-b@{1}` or similar to find earlier commits, including the one you skipped.

Comment: @torek "you can use the `reflog` for `branch-b`": Indeed. I remember you [explaining just that in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25222144/6309).

Comment: @torek I see. Didn't realize the reflog was branch-specific. It shows as expected in the rebased branch. Thank you.